# gradle fails to build Android project on remote jenkins server

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, build

as i am running Jenkins remotely on Ubuntu ec2 server . I used command as follows to install support library :

echo y | ./android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-support"

Which installed Android Support Library, revision 22.2

following items were installed in path /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/extras/android/support :

```
annotations
design
multidex
NOTICE.txt
README.txt
samples
source.properties
v13 (containing android-support-v13.jar and /src folder)
v17 (containing android-support-v17.jar and /src folder)
v4 (containing android-support-v4.jar and /src folder)
v7 (containing android-support-v7.jar and /src folder)
```

but still i have the following error :

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'. > Could not
 find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0. Searched in the
 following locations:
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
 Required by: workspace:app:unspecified > Could not find
 com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0. Searched in the following
 locations:
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.jar
 Required by: workspace:app:unspecified
```

Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

From **Android SDK Manager** download the **Android Support Repository (in Extras)** and an M2 repo of the support libraries will be downloaded to your Android SDK directory

If you are using command line server 
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter 139